# Warning: Illegal string offset on theme options page

Tags: php, errors, theme-options, options, customization

Im creating custom theme options and Im getting this PHP error: Warning: Illegal string offset in ... on line 75

```
// adding the page to menu
add_menu_page('Theme Options', 'Theme Options', 'manage_options', 'rm-options', 'rm_display_options_page');

// form to display options
<form method="post" action="options.php">
            <?php
                settings_fields('rm_theme_options'); // options name
                do_settings_sections('rm-options'); // page
                submit_button();
            ?>
</form>

// adding a section
add_settings_section('rm_general_section', 'General options', 'rm_general_section_callback', 'rm-options');

// register the options
register_setting( 'rm_theme_options', 'rm_theme_options', 'esc_attr' );

// register a field
$some_option_args = array('type' => 'text', 'id' => 'some_option_name', 'name' => 'some_option_name', 'desc' => 'Description');
add_settings_field('some_option_name', 'Some Option', 'pu_display_setting', 'rm-options', 'rm_general_section', $some_option_args);

// finally a function to display the fields
function pu_display_setting($args){
    extract( $args );
    $options = get_option( 'rm_theme_options' );

    switch ( $type ) {  
          case 'text':
              //$options[$id] = stripslashes($options[$id]);  
              //$options[$id] = esc_attr( $options[$id]);
              // this is line 75 where im getting the warning
              echo "<input type='text' id='$id' name='" . 'rm_theme_options' . "[$id]' value='$options[$id]'>";
              echo ($desc != '') ? "<br /><span class='description'>$desc</span>" : "";  
          break;  
    }
}
```

Now when Im trying to save the option, the error is still there and the value of the input is "A", when I check the database, the actual value is just "Array". Whats wrong with the line 75? In the tutorial where I got the display setting function, there were also two more lines which are stripping the slahes and esc_attr.

### EDIT:

Thats now how my code actually is, Im using the function to display the page but I just didnt want to put every piece of code here so it isnt a big mess.
This is how it looks complete:

```
function rm_display_options_page() { ?>
    <div class="wrap">
        <h2><?php echo 'Theme options: ' . wp_get_theme(); ?></h2>
        <div class="description">Theme options description</div>

        <?php settings_errors(); ?>

        <form method="post" action="options.php">
            <?php
                settings_fields('rm_theme_options'); // options name
                do_settings_sections('rm-options'); // page
                submit_button();
            ?>
        </form>
    </div>
<?php
}
```

And the line 75 is:

```
echo "<input type='text' id='$id' name='" . 'rm_theme_options' . "[$id]' value='$options[$id]'>";
```

Comment: What line is 75?

Comment: @BrianFegter I added the comment above the line, before it was after :) This is the line: echo "<input type='text' id='$id' name='" . 'rm_theme_options' . "[$id]' value='$options[$id]'>";

Answer (score 2):

The code you posted has a **major flaw***: it mixes HTML and PHP without properly setting them apart. This code chunk has a PHP function call followed by an HTML string, but since there's nothing telling the file that it should be treated as HTML, the parser says "Hey, `<form` isn't anything I recognize. I'm outta here!"

* That nearly everyone gets hit by at some time when using PHP and HTML. :)

The offending code here is

```
// adding the page to menu
add_menu_page('Theme Options', 'Theme Options', 'manage_options', 'rm-options', 'rm_display_options_page');

// form to display options
<form method="post" action="options.php">
        <?php
            settings_fields('rm_theme_options'); // options name
            do_settings_sections('rm-options'); // page
            submit_button();
        ?>
</form>
```

You have a couple of options here, one is to tell PHP to `echo` the HTML like this:

```
// adding the page to menu
add_menu_page('Theme Options', 'Theme Options', 'manage_options', 'rm-options', 'rm_display_options_page');

// form to display options
echo '<form method="post" action="options.php">';
            settings_fields('rm_theme_options'); // options name
            do_settings_sections('rm-options'); // page
            submit_button();
echo '</form>';
```

Another is to bracket out the PHP parts so the HTML isn't parsed by PHP:

```
// adding the page to menu
add_menu_page('Theme Options', 'Theme Options', 'manage_options', 'rm-options', 'rm_display_options_page');

// form to display options
?>
<form method="post" action="options.php">
        <?php
            settings_fields('rm_theme_options'); // options name
            do_settings_sections('rm-options'); // page
            submit_button();
        ?>
</form>
<?php
 ...
```

*** Update ***

There's a bit of string concatenation that I can't quite wrap my eyes around, so I've changed that here to make it easier for me to grasp. It may help with fixing any errors, too.
It's also best practice to escape attributes in your HTML, so I updated that line to include those functions.

```
echo "<input type='text' id='$id' name='rm_theme_options[$id]' value='" . esc_attr( $options[$id] ) . "' />';
```

Comment: As a developer, the proper technique is to use php tags.

Comment: Since both are supported and useful, I'm not sure there's a "proper" technique. I do my best to follow the WordPress coding standards, but on this one there's not a standard yet (see http://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/coding-standards/php/#comment-9236), although many examples *do* use the opening and closing tags to offset the html (see http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Options_Pages).

Comment: Actually, in this case, that `<form>` needs to be inside a callback, hooked into `admin_menu()`, and the `register_setting()` and `add_setting*()` calls need to be in a callback, hooked into `admin_init`.

Comment: Also, there are other Codex examples of using `echo` for HTML, so that method is perfectly valid (if more challenging to read and maintain). https://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API

Comment: This is not really the place to discuss the relative merits of PHP tags vs `echo` to spit out markup. There are questions on [SO] ([for example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2437144/opening-closing-tags-performance)) and the network has chat rooms were you want to argue your points if you wish. Thanks.

Comment: @morganestes I updated my code and added an edit, please check that. I just didnt include my whole code so its not a big mess, the actual problem starts in the switch. Line 75 is the one with the first echo. And on this line Im getting the php warning.

Comment: @RichardMišenčík I've updated my answer with an update specific to the line 75 echo problem. Take a look and let me know if it helps or if you have any questions about it.

Comment: @morganestes Thanks, In my question I have these 2 lines: $options[$id] = stripslashes($options[$id]);  
            $options[$id] = esc_attr($options[$id]); which are esentially the same thing but stripslashes is added, is it needed or can i get rid of it and just use the esc_attr?

Answer (score 0):

This *appears* to be a PHP syntax issue only:

```
echo "<input type='text' id='$id' name='" . 'rm_theme_options' . "[$id]' value='$options[$id]'>";
```

The first issue is mixing PHP variables and string concatenation. I assume that you need the string `'rm_theme_options[$id]'`, where `$id` is replaced with its value? If so, your string concatenation should reflect that:

```
echo "<input type='text' id='" . $id . "' name='rm_theme_options[" . $id . "]' value='" . $options[$id] . "'>";
```

It is subjective, but I recommend using double-quotes for HTML, and single-quotes for PHP strings. It's just far easier to follow:

```
echo '<input type="text" id="' . $id . '" name="rm_theme_options[' . $id . ']" value="' . $options[$id] . '">';
```

The main advantage of enclosing PHP strings in double-quotes is that you can pass variables directly into the string; but in complex strings that mix double- and single-quotes, that (as you've found out) can just get really complicated.

Comment: Thanks, I already did this when I was trying and editing the code to get it to work, I also replaced the double quotes with single quotes just like your third example in the answer above. I also removed the esc_attr from register_setting, without that it now seems to work and I dont get that error now.